# Kaltlassen: Kann ein Thema jemanden kaltlassen?

Tags: word-choice

> Dieses Thema ist so interessant/kontrovers/umstritten usw., dass es kaum jemanden kaltlässt

Ist dieser Satz vom Stil her richtig oder wie würden Sie es ausdrücken, dass ein Thema für viele Menschen von besonderer Bedeutung ist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Zur stilistischen Angemessenheit von

> ein Thema, das kaum jemanden kaltlässt

kann man keine allgemeingültige Aussage treffen. Es kommt auf den Kontext an.

In einem Gespräch unter Freunden und Kollegen ist der Ausdruck sicherlich häufig. Man sollte sich aber bewusst sein, dass er flappsig ist. In einem Gespräch mit einem Vorgesetzten würde man sich eher anders ausdrücken, z.B.

> Dieses Thema ist so umstritten, dass kaum jemand unbeteiligt bleibt.

Auch in schriftlichen Äußerungen kommt es auf die Umgebung an. Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass die Formulierung in einer Spiegel-Reportage vorkommt, vielleicht auch aml in einem Kommentar der flippigeren Sorte in irgend einer Zeitung, aber nie in einem Nachrichtentext, da man hier nach betont sachlichen Ausdrücken sucht, die nicht durch Untertöne angereichert sind. Auch in einem Geschäftsbrief wird man solche flappsigen Formulierungen nicht verwenden.

Comment: Kommt sicher auf den Vorgesetzten bzw. auf die Branche an. Du musst ja davon ausgehen, dass eine Äußerung darüber, ob etwas jemanden interessiert überhaupt Eingang in den Brief findet. Die Steuererklärung wird es eher nicht sein.

Answer (score 5):

Stilistisch ist das in Ordnung, vermeiden solltest du nur Folgendes:

> Dieses Thema ist so heiß, dass es kaum jemanden kaltlässt.

Es sei denn, du willst belustigen.

Answer (score 4):

Wenn ein Thema niemanden **kalt**lässt, **erhitzt** es meist die Gemüter, oder es **erwärmt** das Herz.

Beide Formulierungen beschreiben ein emotionales Interesse. Das bedeutet, die Formulierung ist dann passend, wenn es sich um Themen handelt, die allgemein emotional betrachtet werden. 
Ungeeignet wäre die Formulierung wahrscheinlich für technische oder wissenschaftliche Themen, die für die beteiligten von großem Interesse sind, aber eben nicht emotional behaftet.

Man kann also sagen, dass die Formulierung geeignet ist für Themen, die nicht objektiv betrachtet werden oder nicht objektiv betrachtet werden können.

Comment: Interessant ist, dass der Rechtschreibrat der Ansicht ist, dass das Verb zusammenzuschreiben ist. *kaltlassen* ist in der Wortliste extra als zusammengeschrieben gelistet, weil die Wortkombination eine "neue, idiomatisierte Gesambtbedeutung" ergäbe.

Comment: Danke, @tofro, das ist durch die Fettschrift fehlerhaft geworden.